# iOS: using Grand Central dispatcher to change dynamically a UI element

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, viewcontroller

I would like to create a GCD element in a shared static object (say, called Manager) that will, every few seconds, fetch some data from an external repository (e.g. URL) and change a `UIElement` in the application `ViewController`.

My thinking is to:

- initialize the Manager object in the `AppDelegate` initialization methods (as soon as the App gets lunched)
- In the initialization method start an operation queue that fetches the data and, after every fetch, verifies if the new content is different than the previous one (that would be locally stored in a variable inside the Manager class.)
- If the content is different change the `UIElement` (e.g. if it is a string then the `UILabel` would change, if it is an Image URL resource then the `UIIMage` will change).

I have no idea on how to **access to the `UILabel` element from the Manager class**. Am I going in the wrong direction or is there some other way/pattern to do this? (I suspect that I need to create a static Logic class that can be accessed by the callback methods function inside from the Manager class and that have reference to the `ViewController` that contains the `UIElements`)

Any simple but good tutorial would be of much help.

Comment: how about [NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller). It can notify you what object is changed so you could reload appropriate UI element.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through delegation. Define a protocol for the Manager class called ManagerDelegate. Then when the manager does its work it can send the delegate information about what it has done or will do.

Some sample delegate methods could be:

```
- (void)managerBeganNewFetchRequest:(Manager *)manager;
- (void)manager:(Manager *)manager foundNewData:(id)data;
- (void)manager:(Manager *)manager didReceiveDuplicateData:(id)data;
```

Here's some info on delegation from the Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html

Answer (score 0):

Post a notification.

In your ViewController with the UILabel you want to change, in viewDidLoad, do something like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) name:@"ManagerUpdated" object:nil];
```

Then in your manager class whenever you want to update the label:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:@"ManagerUpdated" object:nil];
```

You can den send data along with the object: parameter, instead of being nil it can be whatever you want.